# Update queable apex with list iteration for loop to process 10 records at a time

Tags: apex, visual-workflow

I have an existing queuable apex class that is taking a collection of records from an autolaunched flow and passing them via the List recordIDs ivocable variable. There is an iteration for loop to handle the record batching will would auto process the records in batches of 200. I need to udapte this class to that the collection of records is processed in batches of 10. I have tried using for loops to iterate in 10 but I'm only getting the first 10 records and then the whole process stops. Any help would be appreciated!

```
//Implement queueable class
global class ProcessApproval implements queueable {
    
    InvocableVariables[] request;
    public ProcessApproval(InvocableVariables[] request) {
        this.request = request;
    }
    //Invocable method called from flow
    @InvocableMethod    
    public static void ProcessApprovalMethod(List <InvocableVariables> request){
        System.enqueueJob(new ProcessApproval(request));
    }
    public void execute(QueueableContext context) {
        
        //invocable variables 
        String actionToPerform = request[0].actionToPerform;
        List<String> recordIDs = request[0].recordIDs;
        
        
        //try/catch block for error handling
        try {
            //Create list of approval request work items to process based on input of recordIDs
            for( List<ProcessInstanceWorkitem> workItems :[
                SELECT Id, ProcessInstanceId 
                FROM ProcessInstanceWorkitem 
                WHERE ProcessInstance.TargetObjectId IN :recordIDs]){
                    //Create an empty list of Approval Requests
                    List<Approval.ProcessWorkitemRequest> approvalRequests = new List<Approval.ProcessWorkitemRequest>();
                    //For each approval request work item in the list set the action, add comment, add to list
                    for(ProcessInstanceWorkitem workItem : workItems){
                        Approval.ProcessWorkitemRequest req = new Approval.ProcessWorkitemRequest();
                        req.setWorkitemId(workItem.Id);
                        //Set action. Valid inputs are Approve, Reject, Remove
                        req.setAction(actionToPerform);
                        //Set approval comment
                        req.setComments('Processed via backend automation.');
                        //Add this request to the list to be processed
                        approvalRequests.add(req);
                    }
                    //Finally - process the list of requests at once
                    Approval.ProcessResult[] processResults = Approval.process(approvalRequests);
                }
        }
        catch(Exception ex) {
            system.debug('Exception has occured' + ex.getMessage());
            
        }
    }    
    global class InvocableVariables{
        
        //Approve/Reject/Recall action
        @InvocableVariable public String actionToPerform;
        //List of record IDs to process
        @InvocableVariable public List<String> recordIDs;
        
    }
}
```

Comment: Just take the first 10 IDs from the start of the list (or the remainder of the list if smaller) to process those in the queueable, then if the list isn't empty, chain the queueable with the remaining list. I would also recommend putting the invocable method in its own class given that any one class can only contain a single invocable method.

Comment: Chaining is simply calling System.enqueueJob again, with the queueable with updated state (the list with the now processed IDs removed).